# post increment operation in while loop (java)

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Recently i came across this question

```
int i = 10;
while (i++ <= 10) {
    i++;
}
System.out.print(i);
```

The answer is 13 , can some please explain how is it 13?

Comment: What do you think the answer should be, and why?

Comment: The postincrement operator applies *after* (or "post") the expression in which it appears; but before any other expression is evaluated.

Comment: This is tricky.  You might expect the answer to be 12. Why? Because the relational condition evaluation and the branch out of the loop might be assumed to be atomic.  It obviously isn't, but it's not an irrational assumption.  It is hard to conceive that Java "stores" the increment operation and "inserts" it *after* the relational condition is evaluated, but *before* the branch out of the loop.  I wonder what the code produced by this looks like at the assembler/machine language level.

Comment: Conversely, this could boil down to storing the evaluation of the relational condition in a boolean (bit/byte?), performing the increment operation, and then performing the branch-if operation on the stored boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the alternative ways I could wrap my head around this.
Let `f(ref i)` be a function which takes in i by reference and increment it it's value by 1. So `f(ref i) = i + 1`

Now that we have `f(ref i)`, the above code can be written as

```
int i = 10
while( (f(ref i) -1) <=10 )
{
   f(ref i);
}
```

I would replace `f(ref i)` with equivalent i values on its return and get the answer like

```
while(11 - 1 <= 10) {12}
while (13 -1 <= 10) -> break;
```

so i = 13.

Answer (score 9):

- i = 10. Look at i, compare to 10
- i = 10. 10 <= 10, so enter the loop.
- i = 10. increment i (as per the while expression)
- i = 11. In the loop, increment i
- i = 12. Look at i, compare to 10
- i = 12. 12 is not <= 10, so don't enter the loop.
- i = 12. Increment i (as per the while expression)
- i = 13

Comment: Thanks , i missed the last step of increment in while loop .